# How to append null values to spreadsheet using google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```js
function userClicked(userInfo){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
     
  ws.appendRow([userInfo.firstName,userInfo.lastName,userInfo.exm,userInfo.tn,userInfo.a1,userInfo.a2,userInfo.a3,userInfo.a4,userInfo.a5,userInfo.a6,userInfo.a7,userInfo.a8,userInfo.a9,userInfo.a10,userInfo.date,new Date()]);
  
}
```

I have a JS where I have an object userInfo to which I copy values from a form. Now I need the elements of userInfo, say `userInfo.a1`, etc to be appended to a spreadsheet. Now since my form is made such a way that it can return null values also, the appending is turning impossible. If I fill all radio buttons of my form, then data is appended to the spreadsheet, else not.

I want that even if my form radio buttons are for not selected ie null, the data must get appended to my spreadsheet. The current code is as above.

Comment: Use setValue(‘’);

Comment: Could you share an example of `userInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `null` values by `''` (empty strings)

Related

- [How do I remove null values from an array within an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55796457/1595451)
- [Remove specific null items in an array in Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59220416/1595451)